# Make Public Folder on node.js by express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ubuntu-14.04, vps

I have an issue which I can't understand it;

I write an express server and want to make a public folder by that; Here is my code:

```
var app = express();
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  var server = app.listen(constants.httpPort, function() {
    console.log("✔ Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", constants.httpPort, app.get('env'));
  });
```

I have a folder named "img" and there is some images at it;

I run this code on VPS, Ubuntu 14.04.5;

I log in my server
Run app.js (it contains the express code) by PM2

```
 request ip:port/public/img/loading.gif  //It shows image
```

exit server

```
 request ip:port/public/img/loading.gif  //It shows message : Cannot
 GET /img/loading.gif
```

What happens when I exit from server? (I am sure the PM2 process is running)

Comment: Okay i am unsure. Are you saying that the server quits when you try to access the resource ?

Comment: @georoot I am using VPS server and by logging out that happens